# cannot return String in function

Tags: swift

I am having trouble casting an option AnyObject into a string.  Whenever I try to call the fuction my program crashes with `(lldb)`.  This is the function.

```
func name() -> String {
    print(attributes["name"])
    print(attributes["name"]! as! String)

    let name  = attributes["name"]! as! String
    return name
}
```

The output from the prints is:

```
Optional(Optional(Josh))
Josh
(lldb)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: How is `attributes` defined?

Answer (score 0):

In all these examples, `attributes` is defined as:

```
var attributes: AnyObject? = ["name": "Josh"]
```

Looks like the crash occurs due to type-safety issues. Try:

```
func name() -> String? {
    if let name = attributes!["name"] as? String {
        return name
    }
    return nil
}
```

Another option, which is slightly swiftier:

```
func name() -> String? {
    guard let name = attributes!["name"] as? String  else { return nil }
    return name
}
```

Yet another option that would be using a block for the function, so that it doesn't return anything if `attributes` doesn't contain a key `"name"`:

```
func name(block: ((text: String?) -> Void)) {
    guard let name = attributes!["name"] as? String  else { return }
    return block(text: name)
}

// Usage:
name { text in
    print(text!)
}
```

Prints:

> Josh

Comment: This does not compile.

Comment: @appzYourLife Fixed.

Comment: Now it compiles but suggesting to return an empty String when conditions fail is a very bad practice IMO because it's semantically wrong. Nobody's name is an empty String... it would be much better to return an Optional String instead of a dummy default value. Note that I comment here but all answers on this page have the same issue.

Comment: @EricD I disagree. Nobody has no name at all either and checking for empty string or nil makes no difference. If everybody has indeed a name than forced unwrapping is safe and the best choice

Comment: @EricD: `Note that I comment here but all answers on this page have the same issue.` I was still writing my own answer :)

Comment: @appzYourLife Yes, I've upvoted yours as soon as it appeared. Very good one. :)

Comment: @vadian: `checking for empty string or nil makes no difference`. I don't agree. First of all it makes a big difference for the compiler. Secondly using a value of the domain of a type (like `0` for `Int`, `false` for `Bool` and `""` for `String`) to indicate the **absence of value** is something we should never do in Swift (and in modern programming in general).

Comment: @appzYourLife Well said!

Comment: @appzYourLife Of course you are right. My statement is related to the concrete `name` property and Eric's statement `Nobody's name is an empty String`. The absence of a person's name is very unlikely, so an optional is not useful, also because the strong type design of Swift encourages the programmers to avoid optionals as much as possible.

Comment: @vadian: We don't know the data model of this project, but the simple fact of returning `""` when a `name` has not been found cannot be right because we are replacing the absence of value with a `String` value.

Comment: @vadian You have a valid point, but as @appzYourLife said, we don't know the structure of the data model. As far as we know, the model may contain multiple values where `name` has to be an optional, for situations like querying a database where `name` hasn't been set which would otherwise result in a failed initialisation of the object and cause a runtime error.

Comment: Reading the question the code expects a non-optional return value. To fulfill that requirement just `attributes` has to be unwrapped. Of course there are many cases to use optionals but there a many cases as well to use non-optionals for example data from databases which reliably return values for all fields. I'm fighting for considering non-optionals because you can see so many "abuses" of optionals.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say `attributes` is defined as follow

```
var attributes: NSMutableDictionary? = NSMutableDictionary()
```

and can be populated like follow

```
attributes?.setValue("Walter White", forKey: "name")
```

### Optionals

You should design the `name()` function to return a `String` or `nil` (aka `String?` which is an `Optional` type)

```
func name() -> String? {
    guard let
        attributes = attributes,
        name = attributes["name"] as? String else { return nil }
    return name
}
```

The same logic can also be written this way

```
func name() -> String? {
    return attributes?["name"] as? String
}
```

Now if a valid `String` value is found inside `attributes` with key `name` then it is returned. Otherwise the function does return `nil`.

### Invoking the function

When using the function you should **unwrap** the result like this

```
if let name = name() {
    print(name) // prints "Walter White"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if let _string = attributes["name"] as? String {
    return _string
}
// fallback to something else, or make the method signature String?
return ""
```

When working with optionals, you don't want to just wrap things with exclamation points. If the value ever ended up not being a string, or not being there at all in the map, you're code would fail hard and potentially crash your application.

If you need a non-optional String, consider returning an empty string as a fallback method and using the `if let` pattern to return the optional string if it is available.

-- EDIT --

Not sure about the downvote... Here it is in a playground.

```
var attributes = [String:AnyObject]()
attributes["name"] = "test"

func name() -> String {
    print(attributes["name"])
    print(attributes["name"]! as! String)

    let name  = attributes["name"]! as! String
    return name
}

// does not compile
//print(name())

func name2() -> String {
    if let _string = attributes["name"] as? String {
        return _string
    }
    // fallback to something else, or make the method signature String?
    return ""
}

// prints test
print(name2())
```

Comment: Why, then, wasn't there a problem with the preceding `print`?

Comment: just pasted a playground example, my edits will print what you are asking for, the `if let` pattern will let you test against several chained or nested optionals at once without a guard statement.